# python asyncio: Wait in coroutine for intermediate result of another coroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have 2 coroutines (`co_A`, `co_B`) in different classes (`class_A`, `class_B`) that are called regularly by a scheduler.
At some time during the execution `co_B` needs a result that `co_A` is calculating during its run.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
class class_A:
    async def co_A(self):

        # execute time consuming code

        # set result that co_B needs
        self.set_result(result)

        # execute more time consuming code

class class_B:
    async def co_B(self):

        # execute time consuming code

        # wait for result from co_A
        result = await class_A_instance.get_result()

        # execute more time consuming code
```

My approach is to have an empty Future in class_A that gets filled during co_A and in co_B wait in a loop until the Future is set:

```
class class_A:
    async def prepare(self):
        self.fut = asyncio.Future()

    async def co_A(self):

        # execute time consuming code

        # set result that co_B needs
        self.fut.set_result(result)

        # execute more time consuming code

class class_B:   
    async def co_B(self):

        # execute time consuming code

        # wait for result from co_A
        while not class_A_instance.fut.done():
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

        result = class_A_instance.fut.result()

        # execute more time consuming code
```

Is there a better way to do this without having to sleep in a loop until `co_A` has calculated the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whole idea of futures is that you can await for it just like for coroutines, tasks, etc.

```
class class_B:   
    async def co_B(self):

        # execute time consuming code

        # wait for result from co_A
        result = await class_A_instance.fut

        # execute more time consuming code
```

See section "Things a coroutine can do" [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines).

Comment: This approach is correct, but it assumes that co_A is already scheduled.

Comment: @kwarunek The same assumption is present in the OP's code (the version with the `while` loop). The nice thing about this solution is that it's more lightweight than an `asyncio.Event`, and also that it allows transmitting a payload object (whereas an `Event` only carries a Boolean flag).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#event) class to synchronize coroutines. @Mikhail approach is 100% correct but doesn't address that you would like to get notified in the middle of `co_A`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.partially_ready = asyncio.Event()

    async def prepare(self):
        self.partially_ready.clear()

    async def co_A(self):   
        # execute time consuming code

        # set result that co_B needs
        self.partially_ready.set()
        # execute more time consuming code


class class_B:   
    async def co_B(self):

        # execute time consuming code

        # wait for result from co_A
        await A_instance.partially_ready.wait()
        # here A_instance finished some part you would like to wait
```